# Lifetime or Failure Time

Tags: self-study, survival, references, terminology, distributions

#### Lifetime / Survival time / Failure time :

```
          the time to the occurrence of event (always nonnegative) .
```

- Lifetime and Survival time can be synonymous .  But why `Failure time`  can be used as alternative of lifetime / survival time ?

In the book [Statistical Models and Methods for Lifetime Data](http://bookzz.org/book/496581/b38548) , it is written :

*"Survival Analysis consists of techniques for `positive-valued` random variables ."*

Also it has mentioned in the book that :

*"Lifetime is  the time to the occurrence of event (always `nonnegative`) ."*

- Why haven't they mentioned either nonnegative or only positive in both cases ?

Comment: These are all synonyms. The use of one or another of these terms depends on the field. For example, survival time is used in medical research while failure time is used in engineering.

Comment: @ocram But i meant this time denotes length of time to occur the interested event and if  the occurrence of the event is considered as success, then the length of time to occur the event is failure time. Can i think in such way ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your question...

Comment: It is a sad fact that the numerical value of the _lifetime_ is exactly equal to the _time of death_. I suspect that which name is used depends on whether one is a optimist or pessimist.

Comment: @DilipSarwate good saying .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a linguistic point.

For "failure time" to be synonymous with lifetime / survival time, then you can think of "failure time " as meaning "time to failure", whereas I think you might be interpreting it as "time elapsed while the thing is failing".  The time to failure is the same as the survival time.

To address your comment under the post:

> *But i meant this time denotes length of time to occur the interested event and if the occurrence of the event is considered as success, then the length of time to occur the event is failure time.*

Whether the event at the end (failure / death / whatever) is considered a success depends on the context entirely - for instance in a protective component such as a fuse, a short time to failure (lower value of failure/survival time) might be success, whereas for a car tyre, the reverse would be true.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is probably just an editorial glitch in the writing publishing of the book.

Technically, I suppose it is possible in some cases to have a 0, and the authors may have been thinking of some such cases when they wrote one description and not when they wrote the other and no one caught it. E.g. if you are testing light bulbs and some blow out the instant they are switched on.  Hardly the worst editorial glitch ever.

Comment: Ah yes - I see the (positive vs non-negative) distinction you've picked up on, missed that when I read it (+1)! I wonder if that's the confusion for the OP.  Hopefully they will clarify.

Comment: Allowing for a lifetime of $0$ is useful in studies of hospital emergency rooms, for example. Else, how would one take into accounts patients who are DOA (dead on arrival)? Lifetimes of semiconductor chips are modeled as exponential random variables (constant hazard rate) but, at least for the US military, all chips must undergo a _burn-in_ test of 200 hours (as I recall) before they can be installed in military equipment, and it is only _then_ that the constant hazard rate assumption is used. For the _manufacturer_, some chips have already failed when they are first powered on.

Comment: That's another good example.